# How to hide some Usergroups from Django Admin in ManytoMany field

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I have the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    site=models.OneToOneField(Site,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    executor=models.ManyToManyField(People)
```

It is related to the following model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, 
     null=True)
    #department = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices= titles, blank=True, 
    null=True)
```

What I want is that in DjangoAdmin in the field executor only people__title='titleone' was displayed. So that the executor search field would not be overload with other people who cannot ever be related to the Tsk since I have them in the same database.

Comment: You could create an admin form which filled out all unwanted data and then register it into admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can override get_queryset() in admin.py file and can restrict queryset to include only that query which contain people__title='titleone'.